# Problems with searches that include user number

Tags: bug, support, status-completed

As of today, I've been having some weird behavior in searches that include the user number.

If I click on a tag in my user page, so that it performs a search for that particular tag and my user number, I'm getting no hits; for example, searching for `[group-theory] user:742` is returning no matches, even though I've posted over 50 answers in such questions.

**Update:** I can confirm Rahu Narain's observation that if perform the search on a tag in which I've **asked** a question, then the question *is* displayed.

Searching for just the tag seems to produce no problems. Searching only for `user:742` does find some hits, but the page result looks weird. I've tried a few users (not just me), they are all giving me trouble. The problem also seems to be occurring in Meta, with searches for user-and-tag returning no matches even when some should exist.

**Update 2:** I've reported this at the main site; I'm told there will be a temporary fix for the user-page links as well as one for the display problem when searching for a user in the next build.

**Final Update:** The searches seem to be working now. Could a moderator mark this as resolved?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. It looks like it no longer returns questions one has answered for that tag, but only questions one has *asked*. This is inconsistent with the number displayed next to the tag, and the previous behaviour was much more useful, so I hope the SE admins consider this a bug and not by design.

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks; how about a search for just your user number? Are you getting regular behavior, or weird display?

Comment: Yes, that page's layout is definitely broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there was a recent change in the search engine.

See this: [New Stack Exchange Search, Try it out!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out) for other bug reports.

In particular, for your bug, see this: [New Stack Exchange Search, Try it out!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out/76635#76635)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to post what the search looks like tomorrow, when I can do a screen shot.

Answer (score 3):

This should be working now:

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:742+%5Bgroup-theory%5D